# How safe is to use an online SVN repository?

Tags: security, svn, version-control

How **safe** is to use an online SVN repository?

I want to develop collaboratively with some friends. I know you can create non-public accounts in some of those services, but I can't fell confortable to send all of our intelectual products to another company manage. After all, if your idea works, those companies can easily find your source code!

Do you think this care is **important**? If so, what is the best solution?

My question isn't "how good it is" or "which is better", I just want know if you **trust** them and why (or why not).

Below I give you SVN repositories examples:

- [XP-Dev](http://xp-dev.com/)
- [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/)
- [Assembla](http://assembla.com/)

Thank you all!

Comment: you can trust them as much as your mail service. They are safe, but can be broken-in as well. : )

Comment: Also – trust them as much as your online backups and as much as your hosting provider.

Comment: @aaz: at least, hosting providers just is owner of published application.

Comment: @Nishant [Not comforting in the least](http://www.theverge.com/2013/8/14/4621474/yes-gmail-users-have-an-expectation-of-privacy)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is definitely important to be concerned about your source code in the cloud. At the end of the day you have to weigh up the cost of installing, securing, maintaining, backing up yourself vs a $10/month plan with a hosted SVN service. There are always going to be a certain sector that will never upload code into a hosted repo, i.e. banks, military, etc, but for the majority of us the risk is low and minor compared to the benefits of not doing it yourself. Make sure the provider you choose enforces SSL, has regular backups (at least hourly granularity), their datacenter provider is SAS70, and a policy allowing you to download your full SVN repo dump if you choose to leave, or go elsewhere, and how long the provider has been in business, do they have a good track record, and does the provider enforce a password policy.

Comment: It is exactly what I've expected to hear! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

If you have something valuable enough to be stolen, it's time to get a lawyer anyway. Get him involved from the start, have him review whatever agreements the various hosting sites have to offer, and make sure they can be held accountable for breaches of security, including the value of your source code in the hands of competitors.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and tip! So, what about the service, in fact? Do you think I can be stolen whether I use those services? For while I just have an idea, could be early to say how valuable is it. Anyway, I belive I have to take care always.

Comment: There are three avenues to explore: Storage, communication, and usage. Part of your selection criteria should certainly be whether or not you can connect securely. This will prevent most types of vulnerabilities as far as being intercepted. Check: communication. Another part would be the security of the service. Have they been compromised? Do they tell users when they are? What's their reaction time? Check: storage. The last is usage - how secure is your environment? Are you susceptible to keyloggers? Check: usage.